# Deletenig an element from a list while it's being iterated recursively throws exception

Tags: java, list, recursion, java.util.concurrent

I have the following code:

```
private void deletePersonFromList(String dni, ObservableList<Persona> persons){
    for(Persona p : persons){
        if(p.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            if(p.getDNI().equals(dni)) {
                persons.remove(p);
            }
        } else deletePersonFromList(dni, p.getChildren());
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to do, is delete an element in a list if it matches a condition, this is done recursively because said elements can contain a list of elements themselves.

Doing this throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException because the list is being iterated. What approach can help me do this?

This is an issue i'm facing while working on a school assignement, so please don't answer with just code solving it(if posible), i'd like to understand what should I do in this cases and why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is not for ask software questions, please contact Telegram Supporter

Comment: It's not a software question, it's about the API, not the software itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Iterator` instead of foreach:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(of("a", "b", "c"));
        final Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final String value = iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            System.out.println("List: " + list + "\tRemoved: " + value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was about to self answer my question because i just realized that and it worked. I'll accept you question as the answer since you were faster.
Thanks

Comment: I gotta wait 23 hours before awarding the bounty

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Iterator<Persona> iter = persons.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Persona p = iter.next();
    if (p.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
        if (p.getDNI().equals(dni)) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    } else deletePersonFromList(dni, p.getChildren());
}
```

With a for-each through persons a state is maintained.